# 実践データ分析100本ノック61 について

Tags: python

python 実践データ分析100本ノック　ノック61に関する質問です。

上記のコードを実行すると、総輸送コストが1450になり、書籍の1298とは違った結果になってしまいます。

実行環境はjupiter notebook でpulpとortoolpyはどちらもconda promptでインストール済みです。

コードに問題があれば教えて頂きたいです。

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
from pulp import LpVariable,lpSum,value
from ortoolpy import model_min,addvars,addvals

df_tc = pd.read_csv("trans_cost.csv",index_col="工場")
df_demand = pd.read_csv("demand.csv")
df_supply= pd.read_csv("supply.csv")

np.random.seed(1)
nw=len(df_tc.index)
nf=len(df_tc.columns)
pr=list(product(range(nw),range(nf)))

m1=model_min()
v1={(i,j):LpVariable("v%d_%d"%(i,j), lowBound=0) for i,j in pr}

m1 +=lpSum(df_tc.iloc[i][j]*v1[i,j] for i,j in pr)
for i in range(nw):
    m1 += lpSum(v1[i,j] for j in range(nf)) <= df_supply.iloc[0][i]
for j in range(nf):
    m1 += lpSum(v1[i,j] for i in range(nw)) >= df_demand.iloc[0][i]
m1.solve()

df_tr_sol = df_tc.copy()
total_cost=0
for k,x in v1.items():
    i,j = k[0],k[1]
    df_tr_sol.iloc[i][j]=value(x)
    total_cost +=df_tc.iloc[i][j]*value(x)

print(df_tr_sol)
print("総輸送コスト:"+str(total_cost))
```

Comment: 念のため、[書籍の正誤表](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/support/7980html/5875.html) も確認してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　正誤表にも特に記載はありません。

Comment: 私の手元にある「python 実践データ分析100本ノック第1版第1刷」では1296が結果として記載されています。kunifさんが回答で示されている値と一緒です。

Answer (score 0):

配布されている`sample_100knocks.zip`中の該当`answer`と比べると、23行目末尾`df_demand.iloc[0][i]`のインデックスが間違っているようです。

正しくは`i`ではなく`j`であり、`df_demand.iloc[0][j]`となっています。

ちなみにAnaconda環境ではなくjupyter notebookでもない、Windows10の素のPython 3.10.1 では総輸送コストが1296というまた少し違った値になったので、何か他のモジュールの版数とかあるいはCSVデータとかに違いがあるのかもしれません。

---

@ほーりー さんのコメントとか以下記事に総輸送コストは1296と書かれていて特に注釈とか無いため1296が正しいようなので、質問に「書籍の1298」とあるのはtypoのようですね。

[『Python実践データ分析100本ノック』ノック61](https://note.com/toshiyamiyazaki/n/nd1010d6ce73d)
[Python実践データ分析100本ノックを読む](https://bitop.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/11/04/090327)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご回答の通りに修正したところ正しい数値を出力できました。ご指導ありがとうございました